# Regex to extract date with negative lookahead

Tags: regex

I am using this pattern to extract confirmation dates from a text file and converting them to a date object (see my post here [Extract/convert date from string in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392009/extract-convert-date-from-string-in-ms-access)).

The current pattern matches all strings that look like a date, but may not be the confirmation date (which is always preceded by Confirmed by), and moreover, may not have complete date information (*e.g.* no `AM` or `PM`).

```
 Pattern: (\d+/\d+/\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+\s+\w+|\d+-\w+-\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+)
```

Sample text:

```
WHEN COMPARED WITH RESULT OF 7/13/12 09:06:42  NO SIGNIFICANT 
CHANGE; Confirmed by SMITH, MD, JOHN (2242) on 7/14/2012 3:46:21 PM;
```

The above pattern matches the following:

```
WHEN COMPARED WITH RESULT OF 7/13/12 09:06:42  NO SIGNIFICANT 
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
CHANGE; Confirmed by SMITH, MD, JOHN (2242) on 7/14/2012 3:46:21 PM;
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I want the pattern to look for the date in the segment of the text file that begins with Confirmed by and ends with a semi-colon. Also, in order to properly convert the time, the pattern should match only AM or PM at the end. How can I restrict the pattern to this segment and add the additional AM or PM criteria?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any need for a lookahead here, positive *or* negative.  This works correctly on your sample string:

```
Confirmed by [^;]*(\d+/\d+/\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+(?:\s+(?:AM|PM))?|\d+-\w+-\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+);
```

The `[^;]*` effectively corrals the match between a `Confirmed by` sequence and its closing semicolon.  (I'm assuming the semicolon will always be present.)

`+(?:\s+(?:AM|PM))?` makes the AM/PM optional, along with its leading whitespace.

The actual date will be stored in capturing group #1.

Answer (score 2):

In order to match the end of the string, use `$` at the end of your regex. To match the entire phrase "`Confirmed by <someone> on <date>`", use plain text (remember that plain text can be used in a regex as well -- if you aren't using special characters, the matcher will match your query verbatim). You need to use a negative look-ahead to exclude entire words.So maybe something like this:

`Confirmed by (?!\ on\ )(\d+/\d+/\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+\s+\w+|\d+-\w+-\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+)$`

Which will allow you to match a string that starts with "Confirmed by", followed by anything except for " on ", followed by the date that you capture, and the end of the string.

Edit: the negative look-ahead part is tricky, look at the answer below for more reference:

[A regular expression to exclude a word/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/a-regular-expression-to-exclude-a-word-string)

Comment: I tried to use this pattern with the source text using [GSKinner's Reg Exr tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?), but it doesn't seem to capture the date. For the date pattern, the pattern mentioned below (\d+/\d+/\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+\s+(?:AM|PM)); works nicely. But still can't get the negative look-ahead to work.

Comment: I changed the quotes within the negative lookahead to escaped spaces and deleted the square brackets, does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(\d+/\d+/\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+\s+(?:AM|PM));
```

Comment: This will (nicely!) match all dates in the source text. Any ideas how I can restrict to the segment that begins with 'Confirmed by' and ends with a ";"?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is more than often a good enough solution. By turning of the default greedy behavior (using the question mark: `.*?`) the regular expression will instead try to find the shortest match that matches the pattern. A pattern never matches the same string more than once, this means that each `Confirmed by` can only be coupled with one date which in this case is the next to follow.

```
Confirmed by.*?(\d+/\d+/\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+\s+(?:AM|PM));
```